# Php category permissions

Tags: php, user-permissions

I want to make a script that allows certain user to modify or delete a certain item.

For example:
Item 1 - can only be edited by user1;
Item 2 - can only be edited by user2;
All items - can be edited by admin

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need database were you store users and their permissions. Depending on logged in user you check permissions for him and allow or deny certain actions.

Comment: I did it.. I attached the database with the php file. Done two if's and its okey now! Thanks for the help!